# A simpler way to write an if statement with multiple values

Tags: php, if-statement

```
if(($x == "m") || ($x == "k") || ($x == "y") || ($x == "p") || ($x == "z"))
```

I'm sure there is a better approach to this. It isn't ideal to be repeating `$x` multiple times. Is there a better and more simpler way to write the above statement?

EDIT:

```
if($x == ('m' || 'k' || 'y' || 'p')
```

Something like the above perhaps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`in_array`](http://php.net/in-array) like so:

```
if( in_array($x, Array("m","k","y","p","z")))
```

Or you could build a string and test it:

```
if( strpos("mkypz",$x) !== false)
```

Or with regex:

```
if( preg_match("/[mkypz]/",$x))
```

Or with a `switch`:

```
switch($x) {
    case "m":
    case "k":
    case "y":
    case "p":
    case "z":
        // do something
        break;
}
```

The last two probably aren't a good idea, but it depends on exactly what you're doing, where `$x` is coming from, etc.. I just wanted to illustrate that there are many ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could build an array of values and use in_array().

```
$check = array('11','23','44')
if(!in_array($x, $check)){
     .... do stuff 
 }
```

or do a switch

```
switch($x){
   case "11":
   case "23":
   case "44":
       echo "match:" break;
   default: 
       echo "no match"; break;  
   }
```

The possiblilities are endless....

Answer (score 0):

use in_array() , bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )

Answer (score 0):

You can use the in_array() function.

From the php documentation site.

```
<?php
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
    echo "Got Irix";
}
if (in_array("mac", $os)) {
    echo "Got mac";
}
?>
```

[PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could use strpos:

`if ( strpos( "mkyxpz" , $x) !== false )`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, instead of `if`, consider `switch`:

```
switch($x) {
    case 'm':
    case 'k':
    case 'y':
    case 'p':
    case 'z':
        [statements];
        break;
    default:
        [more statements];
        break;
}
```

Notice that the value of `$x` will "fall through" every `case` condition until it reaches a `break` statement.